# MySQL: Joining 4 tables with correct results

Tags: mysql

I am have four tables in my DB for a simple forum that I am coding.

Topics:

```
topic_ID | name | description
```

Threads:

```
thread_ID | topic_ID | name | description
```

Messages:

```
message_ID | thread_ID | title | message | date | user_ID
```

Users:

```
user_ID | name | email | username
```

I want to run one query to do the following:
Display the available topics, the number of threads associated with each topic, the number of messages associated with each topic, the date latest message posted and the user who posted it.

So one row of the result would say something like:

```
Topic: Admin
Threads: 4
Posts: 50
Newest message: 2016/05/18 by pixelled
```

I started with this (which worked):

```
SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.name, count(threads.topic_id) AS 'totals' 
FROM topics
LEFT JOIN threads
ON topics.topic_id = threads.topic_id
GROUP BY threads.topic_id
```

I then added the messages table:

```
SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.name, count(threads.topic_id) AS 'totals', MAX(messages.date) AS 'Newest'
FROM topics
LEFT JOIN threads
ON topics.topic_id = threads.topic_id
LEFT JOIN messages
ON messages.thread_id = threads.thread_id
GROUP BY threads.topic_id
```

But the results of this query show the wrong values for the totals column.

Adding the users table works:

```
SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.name, count(threads.topic_id) AS 'totals', MAX(messages.date) AS 'Newest', users.username
FROM topics
LEFT JOIN threads
ON topics.topic_id = threads.topic_id
LEFT JOIN messages
ON messages.thread_id = threads.thread_id
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.user_ID = messages.user_ID
GROUP BY threads.topic_id
```

Please help me to complete this query so that the correct value shows in the totals column.

Here is the fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f926

Comment: can you provide an sql file  ? ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 count (distinct threads.thread_id)
```

Comment: No, that only counts each thread once, so if it exists it shows 1, else 0. I need the total number of threads associated with each topic

Comment: Have you tried it? It surely counts each thread of a topic once, which is intented, otherwise you would count the messages and users too. Its not only the distinct that changed, just to be sure...

Comment: Tried it in sqlfiddle , works as i intended, gives 0, 1 and 3 as thread count

Comment: I don't understand. I ran it in fiddle and I get 0, 1, and 1.  The same statement as the last one above, but with the DISTINCT added

Answer (score 0):

This was the query that gave the correct results:

```
SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.name, topics.description, count(threads.topic_id) AS 'totals', MAX(m.date) AS 'Newest', users.username
FROM topics
LEFT JOIN threads
ON topics.topic_id = threads.topic_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT thread_id, date, user_id
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY thread_id
) m
ON m.thread_id = threads.thread_id
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.id = m.user_id
GROUP BY threads.topic_id
```

It was duplicating the threads table because it was joined twice.